# Can't install Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit

Tags: system-installation

I have just bought an hp pavilion DV6 ( intel i7 processor + 6G of RAM) running windows 7( 64 bits). I downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 64 bits and correctly burned it to a DVD. My problem starts when I try to boot the computer from DVD as a first step to install Ubuntu. In fact, the home page of Ubuntu is shown without further prompts ( no button of install of try it before install). I tried the process many times without results. Why couldn't I install the 64 bits version of Ubuntu 12.04 ( knowing that my laptop has a 64 bits architecture)?? I would really like to install the 64 bits version to be able to get the most of my laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a usb flash disk for installing Ubuntu. It's a better way.

Comment: ok Thanks, I will try that and let you know if it works:):)

Comment: hope it would help, cause i had the same problem and this worked for me.

Comment: Thanks Dan :) It worked perfectly :) The thread can be considered "Solved" :)